# Nested NSCollection View

Tags: macos, nested, nscollectionview

I am trying to create a nested collection view. First I did for one level.

Created a data model class with String `header`. In app delegate created an array `sectionTitle`. Now in the nib, I added collection view & array controller and did all the bindings following this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009030). Next in `awakeFromNib` I populated some random data

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    int idx = 0;
    NSMutableArray *sectionTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while (idx < 1) {
        HeaderModel *header = [[HeaderModel alloc] init];
        [header setHeader:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", idx]];
        [sectionTitle addObject:header];
        idx++;
    }
    [self setHeaderData:sectionTitle];
}
```

Running it will give me 4 sections. I want to achieve similar layout as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370125/nscollectionview-with-sections-like-in-iphoto). Section title, under it another collection of items. The answer given there only hints at using Nested collection view.

So I added another collection view in the first view prototype. Then I followed the same approach what I did for the first view(with different data model and array).

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    int idx = 0;
    NSMutableArray *sectionTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *groupData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while (idx < 1) {
        HeaderModel *header = [[HeaderModel alloc] init];
        DataModel *name = [[DataModel alloc] init];
        [header setHeader:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", idx]];
        [name setName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name %d", idx]];
        [sectionTitle addObject:header];
        [groupData addObject:name];
        idx++;
    }
    [self setHeaderData:sectionTitle];
    [self setData:groupData]; //NSCollectionView item prototype must not be nil.
}
```

But now I get the error **NSCollectionView item prototype must not be nil.**
How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I have just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22057382/795245)

But somehow by inserting the second NSCollectionView with I.B, you get a corrupted prototype for your inner NSCollectionViewItem. Simply try to extract each associated NSView into its own .xib

Comment: I'll try it. +100 for being the only one to say anything.