# How to create groups in NSCollectionView?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, appkit, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

How to add sections to NSCollectionView?

[image]

Comment: is this maybe what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370125/nscollectionview-with-sections-like-in-iphoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WWDC 2015 Session 225](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-225/) video covers this, albeit without storyboards. One thing that’s not immediately obvious when looking at it is you no longer use Cocoa bindings to get at the data, but instead use a dataSource, similar to how iOS does it (and the more traditional way it was done in OS X).